# Unable to Save en-dash to DB2 column with CCSID 37 through Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, db2, codepages

Am doing migration from CA-Gen to SpringBoot. When I try to insert en-dash(–) in db2 column through CA-Gen its working fine. But when I try to Insert data from SpringBoot it saved as '$(26)'. If I fetch value in Java, DB2 returning empty. Also I tried in AQT with SQL query same issue occur. DB2 Column has CCSID as 37 and type is varchar(2000).

Comment: It seems that CCSID 37 is limited to 256 chars only (not Unicode) and the en-dash character is not supported by this DB2 encoding. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_37

Comment: Maybe a solution would be to make the database (or table) to use a different encoding, preferrably something with Unicode support, at least on the basic planes (the first 65k chars).

Comment: Thank you. But am wondering how its working for CA-Gen code but not for Java

Comment: I would suggest you inspect some of the rows with this issue. Some apps use dirty tricks to store values that the character enconding doesn't accept. Typically they "preprocess" the character before saving to use a 2-char representation of it (similar to Base-64). Of course, when reading it back they also need to process it again to restore it. I guess you'll need to either switch to a Unicode table/column, or you should try  mimic the solution (trick) used by CA-Gen.

Comment: Thank you. That would be the only solution